# How to verify if flutter packages send data without my knowledge

Tags: flutter, dart, privacy

I'm developing a Flutter app that uses several third-party packages. I want to ensure that none of these packages send any sensitive data without my knowledge or explicit authorization. Is there a tool or method available to help me verify if any of these packages are sending data to external servers or APIs without my consent?

I've already reviewed the documentation and GitHub repositories of the packages I'm using, but I couldn't find any explicit information regarding data collection. Additionally, I'm not familiar with all the underlying implementation details, which makes it difficult for me to ensure data security.

Is there a tool or approach I can use to monitor the network traffic or inspect data transmissions from the packages within my Flutter app? I want to be proactive in protecting my users' privacy and complying with data protection regulations.

Any guidance or suggestions on how to tackle this issue would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you’re developing for web I think the built-in „Network” tab in your browser should be enough.

For Android, in Android Studio there is an App Inspection tab, by default on the bottom of the screen, where you can select „Network Inspector”. You can also find this tab by going **View > Tool Windows > App Inspection**. You can find the documentation here (https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/network-profiler) but the tool looks really similar to the browser tab.

As for iOS I do not have experience with xCode’s Network tool, but here’s the documentation that might help you: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/analyzing_http_traffic_with_instruments

To monitor the network traffic from packages, simply use them in your app and check using the tools above if any data is sent that was not authorised by you

Answer (score 0):

### Flutter has a built-in network view

that makes you inspect HTTP, HTTPS, and web socket traffic in your Flutter application
like the network profile in Android, and a Network tab in the browser for the web,

That works for cross-platforms without having to deal with every platform,
It's called Network View in DevTools in your Flutter environment,
check the official [blog](https://docs.flutter.dev/tools/devtools/network) for information on how and why you should use it